# Values_list with flat=True still showing brackets

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, jinja2

so I have this html code:

```
<legend><h1 > Weapons that this character has </h1></legend>
    <div>
        <ul style="list-style-type:none" >
            {% if request.GET.idChar %}
            <li >{{ charname }} Has Maihand {{ mh }} and Offhand {{ oh }}</li> 
            {% else %}
            <li>no</li>
            {% endif %} 
        </ul>


    </div>
```

The issue is that {{ charname }}, {{ mh }} and {{ oh }} are still displaying the brackets after i added flat=True in their line in views.py, in fact they stopped showing the parenthesys, but still showing the brackets. I also tried named=True, named=bool, flat=bool. Also tried values instead of values_list...

Views.py:

```
def character_weapons (request):
    idchar = request.GET.get('idChar')
    weapons = Characterweapons.objects.filter(characterid__exact=idchar).values_list('weaponid','categoryid_id')
    charname = Characters.objects.filter(characterid__exact = idchar).values_list('name', flat=True)
    print("charname: ")
    print(charname)
    if weapons[0][1] == 1:
        mh_id = weapons[0][0]
        oh_id = weapons[1][0]
    elif weapons[0][1] == 2:
        oh_id = weapons[0][0]
        mh_id = weapons[1][0]
    mh = Weapons.objects.filter(weaponid__exact=mh_id).values_list('weaponname', flat=True)
    oh = Weapons.objects.filter(weaponid__exact=oh_id).values_list('weaponname', flat=True)


    context={"mh": mh, "oh": oh,"idchar": idchar,"charname": charname}

    return render(request,'users/character_weapons.html', context)
```

If someone knows how to fix it please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values_list()` with `flat=True` returns a list of values, so you have to extract the value with an index of `0` since your queries appear to always return only one row:

```
context={"mh": mh[0], "oh": oh[0],"idchar": idchar,"charname": charname[0]}
```

Comment: yep sorry, I had to wait like 10 minutes hehe

Answer (score 0):

It's a flat list, but it's still a list. If you want to output it in one go, use the [`|join`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#join) filter.

```
{{ mh|join:"," }}
```